# Grunt-compass can't compile multiple files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-compass

This is my Gruntfile.js(part of it) that has the code for compass directories as you can see bellow :

```
 compass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
        sassDir: '*/docs/scss/*.scss',
         cssDir: '*/css/*.css',
         outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }
      }
    },
```

I'm using grunt-newer to compile only recently edited elements in project folders.

Bluntly put i have two projects folders in my main development folder, and when i run grunt watch or grunt compass i want to compile the sass that has the newest changes in it so i can work on multiple project in the same time . I ve tried some stuff but i only get this :

**You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory .**

Is there a way to work around this ?

I want to work with app1 (folder) app2 app3 and app4 and when i run grunt compass the compiler to check all files and to modify only the ones that have changes in them .

Comment: Regarding the use of * at the beginning of both directory configuration items: Is it your intention that for each matched `sassDir` a corresponding (similar base path) `cssDir` will be used?

Comment: As i think about this , it's kind of complicated , multiple projects idea might not work as well as i thought . I will delightfully wait for other answers , in the mean time i ll try to find a solution based on Jason Aller's answer , tnx by the way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration you provided both `sassDir` and `cssDir` were not specified as directory strings as they also included file extensions.

`sassDir` expects as string that points to the source directory where you keep your Sass stylesheets.

`cssDir` expects a string that points to the target directory where you keep your CSS stylesheets.

Thus a first step would be to revisit the entire set of instructions for how to specify the [configuration](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass).

Comment: Yes i am aware of that dont know if there is a loophole here . I think this idea is doomed ill try to further work on it and repost my findings :) . I hope i find something because this can be an awsome way to work with multiple projects in one folder .